# Load PartialView for AJAX and View for non-AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I wanna implement something like in facebook:

- after left click on photo, it is loaded via AJAX
- after middle click on scroll, it is loaded normally with additional layout

For now I have a View, which is loaded in Controller in two different methods:

```
public ActionResult Overview()
{
    return View("Overview");
}

public ActionResult OverviewPartialView()
{
    return PartialView("Overview");
}
```

And in jquery script it looks like this:

```
$(contentContainer).load(_link + 'PartialView');
```

My question is, is there a better way to solve that problem?
I have tried with something like that in _ViewStart:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    if (IsAjax)
    {
        Layout = null;
    }
}
```

And something like that in Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView();

    return View();
}
```

But in those solutions I had a problem with cache, after opening a page with layout, in AJAX request also that page with layout was loaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a single action:

```
public ActionResult Overview()
{
    return View();
}
```

and inside `_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Another possibility is to use the following:

```
public ActionResult Overview()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    return View();
}
```

then if you want to avoid *caching* problems you could use a POST request instead of GET:

```
$.post(_link, function(result) {
    $(contentContainer).html(result);
});
```

or use `$.ajax` with GET and specify `cache: false` which will append an unique query string parameter to avoid browsers caching:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _link,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        $(contentContainer).html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 great answer, help me a lot, it works now without additional amount of code, what is really important for me :)

Comment: The @{ Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "..." } seems a real  elegant solution, guess I'll give that a whirl.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a semi global solution with an ActionFilter. This example transforms the original ViewResult to PartialViewResult, if the request is AJAX (XHR)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AjaxifyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() ||
            !(filterContext.Result is ViewResult)) return;

        var view = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        filterContext.Result = new PartialViewResult
        {
            TempData = view.TempData,
            ViewData = view.ViewData,
            ViewName = view.ViewName,
            ViewEngineCollection = view.ViewEngineCollection
        };
    }
}
```