# ajax request to return partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, partial-views

I'm trying to make request returns on ajax updated partial view. Apparently request is not returned from the ajax-function.
Here ajax-code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doAjaxPost(myid) {
    // get the form values
    var ApplSort = $('#DropDownListSort').val();
    var radio_check_val=0;

    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('radio').length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByName('radio')[i].checked) {
            radio_check_val = document.getElementsByName('radio')[i].value;
        }
    }

    // alert("myid=" + myid +";"+ "ApplSort=" + ApplSort + ";" + "radio_check_val=" + radio_check_val);

    $.ajax(
 {
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     data: { ApplSort: ApplSort, radio_check_val: radio_check_val, myid: myid },
     UpdateTargetId: "tabledata",
     dataType: 'html',
     url: 'Partner/PartnerApplications',
     success: function (data) { 
      var result = data;
      $('tabledata').html(result);
},

     error: function (error) {
         alert('Ошибка AJAX-запроса. Обновите страницу!');
     }
 });
}
</script>
```

Fail is called and the page is completely updated.

Here's updated content in the view:

```
<div id="target">
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Partner/PartnerApplicationsPartial.cshtml")
</div>
```

controller's code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PartnerApplications(int[] ApplSort, int[] radio_check_val, int[] myid)
    {
        MordaPartner MrdPrt = new MordaPartner(Server, Request);

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var obj = MrdPrt.morda_obj.CookieAuthenticationPartner(Server, Request, Response, MrdPrt.PartnerLogin, MrdPrt.PartnerPassword);
            if (obj != null)
            {
                //alert("ApplSort=" + ApplSort + ";" + "ApplSelectOffer=" + ApplSelectOffer + ";" + "ApplSelectAuction=" + ApplSelectAuction + ";" + "ApplSelectNoOffer=" + ApplSelectNoOffer);

                var objs = from s in MrdPrt.morda_obj.entities.applications where s.application_user_city == obj.partner_city & s.application_blocked != 1 orderby s.application_id ascending select s;

                return Json(new { data = this.RenderPartialViewToString("PartnerApplicationsPartial", objs) });
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Registration");

            }
        }
        else { return RedirectToAction("PartnerApplications"); }
    }
```

RenderPartialViewToString it was taken from here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/7150/implementing-renderpartialviewtostring-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

script is loaded:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Question: in the same function PartnerApplications you return JSON or HTML but your JavaScript code handles HTML only. Is it what you intend to do?

Comment: Yes, indeed ... And how can I return only the HTML?

Comment: BTW, if it's an Ajax request, you can't redirect ajax requests.  You need to return JSON to let your Javascript redirect the user.

Answer (score 1):

I think your easiest solution since you are just wanting to do a partial...

```
@using( Ajax.BeginForm( "PartnerApplications", 
                        null, 
                        new AjaxOptions() { 
                             HttpMethod = "POST", 
                             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,  
                             UpdateTargetId = "target", 
                             LoadingElementId = "AjaxSearch" }, 
                        new { id = "UserSearchForm" } ) ) {
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" placeholder="Enter Search" />
}
```

This is an ability that is built into MVC that makes it **VERY** easy to update an element with the results of a partial.

All this is saying is that you want a new Ajax Form that calls the `PartnerApplications` Action.  You want the action called with an `HttpMethod` that is a `POST` request and you want the results to replace (`InsertionMode.Replace`) the existing elements in the `target` (whatever that may be) and while the request is taking place you want the element `AjaxSearch` visible (this is optional, but something I use to show that it's working).

This will generate the required JavaScript for you and until you get into something beyond simply returning a partial works EXCELLENT!

EDIT: Also you will need to update your Action...

`return Json(new { data = this.RenderPartialViewToString("PartnerApplicationsPartial", objs) });`

needs changed to....

`return PartialView("PartnerApplicationsPartial", objs);`

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS:**

Without knowing the data better that is being sent to the server I can't tell you what to write in order to replace that method. I would however look at the properties of `new AjaxOptions(){}` because it has some additional properties that allow you to specify the name of a JavaScript function to call on four states (before/after/success/fail) of the Ajax request.  So if you are needing to calculate something you can do this by specifying a JavaScript function that will be processed before the Ajax request is submitted.

Also you are doing a lot more work then needed to get the selected radio button value (especially since you are using jQuery).

You can replace...

```
var radio_check_val=0;

for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('radio').length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementsByName('radio')[i].checked) {
        radio_check_val = document.getElementsByName('radio')[i].value;
    }
}
```

with something similar to....

```
var radio_check_val = $('radio').filter(':checked').val(); 
//this will only work if there is only one set of radio buttons on the page.
//Otherwise you will need to add a name to the selector.
```

Comment: Which in this case Ajax function should be?

Comment: I don't understand the question can you elaborate?

Comment: The first block of my code:
<script type="text/javascript">
function doAjaxPost (myid) {

   ....

     $. ajax (
  {
   
What should be written here?

  });
}
</ script>

Comment: Help me, please! How to make AJAX request for multiple forms or controllers?

Comment: Please don't take this wrong, but I have little desire to continue putting time into answering a question when the asker can't accept an answer from someone or upvote them if it  helped....

Comment: @KotFantazer if this worked then mark the answer as the one that solved your problem (this holds true for any question you ask).  Also if you piece together a solution from multiple responses then be sure to upvote all the ones that helped you as well as marking the "MOST" helpful one as a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You should not `RedirectToAction`. Instead of redirect return `PartialView('Registration');`.

Related questions:
[MVC Return Partial View as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730777/mvc-return-partial-view-as-json).
[Load PartialView for AJAX and View for non-AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562814/load-partialview-for-ajax-and-view-for-non-ajax-request)

Comment: Downvoted as it's a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/171858).  This answer provide no *actual answer*.

Comment: @ErikPhilips the answer back in 2012 was to use `PartialView` instead of `RedirectToAction`. How is that link-only answer?